# Read a .txt file with javascript and fill a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Money', ''],
          ['US', 80.21, 'United States']
          ['JP', 10.01, 'Japan']
...
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        geomap.draw(data, options);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 750px; height: 550px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I need directly read a .txt file with the following content:

```
['Country', 'Money', ''],
['US', 80.21, 'United States']
['JP', 10.01, 'Japan']
```

And fill the array used here:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([...]);
```

How can I make this is javascript?

Thank you
Daniele

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you get stuck at some point?

Comment: The problem is how can I directly read the .txt file and fill the array?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is properly-formatted JSON, ie.:

```
[
    ["Country","Money",""],
    ["US",80.21,"United States"],
    ["JP",10.01,"Japan"],
    ...
]
```

Then you can just load it in with AJAX real simply and run it through `JSON.parse()` to get the desired array. There are plenty of tutorials on retrieving JSON from a file, so please give it a try and let us know if you have more specific problems.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand.  How can I read the .txt file and convert it to a valid array to use with arrayToDataTable() ?